# set ONE on.click for more actions - javascript and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

I have some dynamic generate buttons that will take me to a specific page.

I need to retrieve the `data-num` automatically generated for every button, use it to set the jQuery selector for the same button. So when I click the button, I will be redirect to the page (of pdf.js).

In my solutions though, I need to click two times to go to the page.

- the first click is to set the variable `i`
- the second click is to actually go to the page

I'm searchig for a fancy solution that allows me to do one click only

```js
$('.pag').click(function(){
 let i= $(this).data('num');
 //let desiredPage= $(this).data('num');
 console.log(i);

 console.log(i);
  $('#pag-'+ i).click(function(){
queueRenderPage(i);
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div id="pag-1" data-num="1" class="prev-next pag">1</div>
    <div id="pag-2" data-num="2" class="prev-next pag">2</div>
    <div id="pag-3" data-num="3" class="prev-next pag">3</div>
    <div id="pag-4" data-num="4" class="prev-next pag">4</div>
     .....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply execute `queueRenderPage()` on the first click with the corresponding number:

```js
$('.pag').click(function() {
  let i = $(this).data('num');
  queueRenderPage(i);
})

//
function queueRenderPage(i) {
  console.log("queueRenderPage("+i+")");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div id="pag-1" data-num="1" class="prev-next pag">1</div>
    <div id="pag-2" data-num="2" class="prev-next pag">2</div>
    <div id="pag-3" data-num="3" class="prev-next pag">3</div>
    <div id="pag-4" data-num="4" class="prev-next pag">4</div>
     .....
```

Comment: oh ok, I was overthinking about something really stupid.
Thank you so much!

Comment: No, problem! Glad I could be of help!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use a function to execute this.

```js
$('.pag').click(function(){
 let i= $(this).data('num');
 //let desiredPage= $(this).data('num');
 console.log(i);
 queueRenderPage(i);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div id="pag-1" data-num="1" class="prev-next pag">1</div>
    <div id="pag-2" data-num="2" class="prev-next pag">2</div>
    <div id="pag-3" data-num="3" class="prev-next pag">3</div>
    <div id="pag-4" data-num="4" class="prev-next pag">4</div>
     .....
```